# Enterprise Library 5 - execute non query negative result

Tags: database, stored-procedures, enterprise-library-5

I have the following code using microsoft enterprise library 5:

```
Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("myConStr");
int rowsAffected = database.ExecuteNonQuery("[DeleteCustomer]", cboCustomers.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

The myConStr is correctly defined in the app.config (it works for other EL-based queries). The DeleteCustomer SP is defined as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCustomer
  @CustomerID nchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    delete from dbo.Customers
    where CustomerID = @CustomerID
END
```

In the documentation of the ExecuteNonQuery metod the result is said to return the number of rows affected.

However, I always get the result "-1", even if the deletion works fine. What's wrong? What can I do to get the number of deleted records?

Thanks,
Lucian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count (indicating the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement) is not returned."